# Finding the first digit of $2^{74207281}-1$ (new biggest prime record)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question

I heard that the record for finding the largest prime number was broken a few days ago with the following Mersenne prime
$$2^{74207281}-1$$
also called $M_{74207281}$. Now my question is: it is possible to compute the first digit (from the left) of this number 'by hand'?

Comment: By first do you refer to the left or to the right?

Comment: @sinbadh Thank you, from the left!

Comment: When saying 'by hand', would you allow using normal (scientific) calculators, the kind that does logarithms and goes up to $10^{99}$ (as opposed to a full computer and dedicated software capable of representing all the 22 million digits)? Or do you really mean "with pen and paper"?

Comment: Well, the ideal thing would be only using pen and paper, but I realize that this would be too long, so we are allowed to use a standard scientific calculator.

Comment: Its two middle digits are $58.$

Comment: Instead of "first" and "last" and "right" or "left", the term should be "most significant" and "least significant".

Comment: Also, in binary representation, that digit is $1$. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
? 10^(frac(p*log(2)/log(10)))
%81 = 3.003764180846061820528342824
```

So, the first digits are $3003764180846061820...$

To calculate the first digit by hand, you have to calculate $74207281\times log_{10}(2)$ upto $4$ digits after the comma and to take the fractional part.

Then you have to calculate $10$ to the power of that number and truncate. Could be done by hand, but would be difficult.

Comment: @OP if you want more, here are a few additional ones: 30037641808460618205298609835916771802

Comment: I know, I noticed it when I used a higher precision.

Comment: @mrf: Yours seem to be off too, with two independent sources I get
$30037641808460618205298609835916605005\dots$

Comment: $$22\ 338\ 618$$ digits. I am curious how long the double-check will take.

Comment: `Prelude> take 40 . show $ 2^74207281 - 1`
`"3003764180846061820529860983591660500568"`
`(2.90 secs, 501971752 bytes)`

Comment: @gammatester You're right, I was too optimistic setting the precision.

Comment: You just have to look at the fractional part and compare it to $\log_{10} 2, \log_{10} 3,\log_{10} 4,\dotsc$ until you know the first digit.

Comment: PARI can calculate that number completely! The digit sum is $100\ 537\ 543$.

Comment: @Peter How did you find that? Using PARI I got overflow error.

Comment: Allocatemem() doubles the work space. Do this until the work space is big enough.

Answer (score 1):

First digits :

> ```
> 3003764180846061820529860983591660500568758630303014848439416933455477232190679942968936553007726883204482148823994267278352907009048364322180153481996522413722876843102133862845736663615066675321227728593598640577802568756477958658321420511711096358442629365726503872407101479826313204371431291121983921887612885039587719203550171864386658099542863444605366067617179336837496247567825783617310448839341553870852508685372972059312516068497815326704147449282948834494294439990037768310724968682506228660399788845410622342191545046452523868463034697248073341558528894973747787053275941448082695460497456828866626343377860615513544982943927889697172778141702478578408251738141699795297188313782581564608555984048010122779636641181623187402419844463395711475008938733504717522823092769609083682182574758579493336886487816470849356003894428166151012698929416209237005839204383031555766751286977273530159661985701199715089754997694301136325207049765960186628185272133382975016900338946922123296485757802701419640294542973795987529
> ```

Last digits :

> ```
> 66899171865137661519802116968797652141490953415212910857051284673598768690185271904942257300495816397525852539385053511561005650888650415738022663320276450183286594189674893176180397372990308168458435170835102089043676200149565779472442501535620998561290570036272472745402151726838956502770332764838294600205565782168765834170009350785028775004659016772336142517609382919278760066514029974961234186924815072110183841065704849092928560900884902955834170658601438843513844182462608969960624663300180408268566068553042312452267239351701254063934290920630706805289782939553784836331982240636162655281521278680346794370033755641577681719012062559469081273978710860347811180188837898128568440669359271612444713805577302483892184777905493456249144515504366735435257646973008855321674803866037094498725552912123074801792765597096176486305356033886997788467889060830923906229428002877708466815350114276229212218369040454779639313670134014480149404704116966334745646885160717774014762912462113646879425801445107393100212927181629335931494239018213879217671164956287190498687010073391086436351
> ```